# What are zsh equivalent to bash's shopt -s globstar and shopt -s dotglob?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I need `zsh` equivalent to `bash`'s `shopt -s globstar` and `shopt -s dotglob`. How can I do that?

**UPDATE 01:**
As per @muru's answer, I used `setopt globdots` in the `zsh` shell, and ran the following command:

```
for i in INSTALL_USER_FILES/** ; do echo "=> '$i'" ; done
```

But, the result was only:

```
=> 'INSTALL_USER_FILES/.local'
```

And nothing within the `.local/` directory was listed recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive globbing is the default in zsh, it doesn't need to be enabled. [The `**` glob](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing) is simply syntactic sugar here:

> A pathname component of the form ‘`(foo/)#`’ matches a path consisting
> of zero or more directories matching the pattern `foo`.
>
> As a shorthand, ‘`**/`’ is equivalent to ‘`(*/)#`’; note that this
> therefore matches files in the current directory as well as
> subdirectories.

The equivalent of `dotglob` is [`GLOB_DOTS`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing):

> **`GLOB_DOTS`**
>
> Do not require a leading ‘`.`’ in a filename to be matched
> explicitly.

It can be enabled for an individual glob using the `D` flag:

```
% mkdir foo; touch foo/{bar,.bar}; echo foo/*(D)
foo/.bar foo/bar
```

Comment: The `setopt globdots` fixed a part of the problem, but recursively listing is not yet fixed? I've updated the question.

Comment: Tried `**/` and that only recursively listed the directories, I also need the files?

Comment: @rusty the `/` forces the match of directories, use `**/*` for recursive match of everything

Comment: Also I did not get how to use `(*/)#` ?

Comment: Thanks. That solved the question.

Comment: @rusty `(*/)#` works identically to `**/`: just `(*/)#` will list directories recursively, and `(*/)#*` will recursively list everything